# Capistrano local git repository cloning to remote asks for password despite SSH keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

Totally new to Capistrano.

I have a local git repository that I want to publish to my remote server. I've followed other answers here and came up with this configuration:

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'

set :application, "app_name"
set :repository, '~/Dropbox/app/.git'
set :user, 'user_name'
set :deploy_to, 'ssh://remote_host/~/railsApps/app_name'
set :scm_verbose, true
set :deploy_via, :copy

default_run_options[:pty] = true

server "remote_server", :web, :app, :db, :primary => true

set :scm, :git
set :branch, "master"

ssh_options[:keys] = %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa)

after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"
```

This no longer asks for a password for the remote server, but fails always with the following error:

```
The --deployment flag requires a Gemfile.lock. Please make sure you have checked your Gemfile.lock into version control before deploying.
```

I am definitely including the Gemfile.lock file in my git repo.

If I change the Capistrano configuration to clone from the remote git folder to which I push (which is in that same server) then I don't get an error but it asks for my password every time I try to connect.

Help please.

**Note** that SSH key pairing works fine when used from the CLI for regular SSH connection.

**Solution**

Thanks to Tigraine I was able to solve it. In the hopes that this helps someone else, here is what finally did the trick:

Tigraine is correct in that the paths are local to the remote server, but I was getting an error when trying to use local paths, Capistrano kept searching on my local machine and throwing errors when it couldn't find those paths.

What I had to do was add the `local_repository` to the config and then everything worked. So the bits I changed are these:

```
set :local_repository, '~/Dropbox/app_name/.git'
set :repository, '~/railsApps/app_name.git'
set :deploy_to, '~/railsApps/app_name'
```

The `local_repository` path is local to my machine and the `repository` and `deploy_to` paths are local to the remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Capistrano always executes it's commands **on** the remote server you are deploying to.
This means that all paths you use like in `set :deploy_to` are local paths on the server.

In my case the config looks something like this:

```
set :scm, 'git'
set :repository,  "<repo url>"
set :branch, 'master'
set :git_shallow_clone, 1
set :scm_verbose, true

set :deploy_to, '/var/www/app'
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
```

The important part here is the `:deploy_to` that is a local path on the server *not a SSH path*. **This is where your config is wrong**!

This gets even more important if you look at the commands capistrano then runs. It for example will usually do things like `bash cd /var/www/app && bundle instal ...`.
If the path is not local the command will most likely fail.

Secondly this also means that Capistrano will deploy to your Git Server **from** your Remote Server, so you have to make sure the remote server has access to the Git Server.
The `ssh_options[:keys]` therefore specifies the local SSH key used to connect to that remote_server, while on the server the default key from `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` will be used.

You can avoid having to set up your SSH key on the Server by using SSH Agent forwarding by including `ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true`. This will simply forward your local SSH agent socket to the server and use that (good because your key never leaves your machine)

More info on SSH Agent forwarding can be found [here](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html)

Comment: I did try the SSH forwarding and that made no difference. But please note that it actually seems to work as it is configured now, just that I get an error for the Gemfile.lock file not being present.

Comment: Did you try running bundler locally to see if the Gemfile.lock is up to date?

Comment: Yes, same problem. I'd be willing to rewrite the config so that it deploys from the repo folder on the server itself if I could figure out how to do it. Which is preferred?

Comment: It should not matter. Try logging into your server with SSH and run the bundle install there maybe there are some gem dependencies differently from your dev machine? .. also look at the server if the Gemfile.lock is really there .. maybe it's in the wrong path?

Comment: In fact, I think deploying from the repo on the server is preferred since it takes a lot less time than uploading the zipped tmp file. But if I try to use a local path for the repository it gives me an error. If I use a path with `ssh://` then it asks for the password.

Comment: bundle install on the server works fine. I do have to add `--path vendor/bundle` but, again, this works fine if I use the deploy from the server's git repo option.

Comment: Why do you need the `ssh//` if you are already on the server with capistrano? try a local path on the server instead..
Or do you SSH into one server and then deploy to another one in that network?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13056/discussion-between-kakubei-and-tigraine)

Comment: If I leave it as a local path it tries to look for it on my local machine and gives me an error. To clarify, the capistrano settings and files are on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Thins to check:

Check in the remote server for .ssh folder and make sure your ssh key(id_rsa.pub) is added to authorized keys with no space appended.

do ssh-add from you local folder from where you are running the cap script.

Check for the permissions of .ssh folder on remote, it should be 700 and files inside with 600 permission.

```
If I change the Capistrano configuration to clone from the remote git folder to which I push (which is in that same server) then I don't get an error but it asks for my password every time I try to connect.
```

Now clone it from the git,

Comment: ssh key paring works fine, I can login without problems using a standard SSH from the CLI. Sorry for the -1 I was trying to get rid of an accidental +1 and I should have explained the fact that SSH key pairing works fine in my original post.

Comment: just check if there is any config/deploy/staging.rb or production.rb or development.rb files which is overriding the deploy script credentials.